# Magento 1.7: make whole productgrid clickable

Tags: magento, product

I wan't to make my whole productgrid clickable in magento 1.7. So not only the images and the productname, but also the white space around it.

Anyone with a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

In `app/design/frontend/default/your_company/template/catalog/product` edit the file called `list.phtml` under the grid mode section (or the list mode) you will see an opening list-item that looks like

```
<li class="item<?php if(($i - 1) % $_columnCount == 0) : ?> first<?php elseif($i % $_columnCount == 0) : ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
```

You can add the `window.open` javascript function inside of an `onclick` event and your code will look like the following:

```
<li class="item<?php if(($i - 1) % $_columnCount == 0) : ?> first<?php elseif($i % $_columnCount == 0) : ?> last<?php endif; ?>" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>', '_self'); return false;">
```

Note: You can change the second parameter in `window.open` to something else like `_blank` if you want the link to open in a new tab/window. [See here for more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open). You might want to add a little CSS to change the list item hover to a pointer cursor e.g.

```
.category-products li:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this using JS and css

Using jQuery example (assuming that you are using the default css classname, add this code to a js file that will be included on your product list page)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('ul.products-grid').click(function(e) {
         if($j(e.target).is("img"){
             window.location.href = $(e.target).closest("li").find('a:first').attr("href");
         }
     });
 });
```

CSS

```
.products-grid li:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/7XR5t/2/

Comment: Thanks! Previous answer already did the job. But jsfiddle is a very usefull tool.